# how to provide change notification for a property when a subproperty changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

This is such a basic question, but I don't think I've done this before despite having bound so many properties. I originally was planning to bind a class called TimeScale to various objects.
In class A we have a dependency property that I want to call change notification on. However, change notification is not done manually through this class.

```
public TimeScale AxisTimeScale
{
    get { return (TimeScale)GetValue(AxisTimeScaleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AxisTimeScaleProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty AxisTimeScaleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("AxisTimeScale",
        typeof(TimeScale), typeof(SignalPanel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new TimeScale()));
```

this binds to source class B

```
private class B
{
    private TimeScale _GraphTimeScale;

    public TimeScale GraphTimeScale
    {
        get { return _GraphTimeScale; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _GraphTimeScale)
            {
                _GraphTimeScale = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GraphTimeScale");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at it again I guess all I really want is to call propertychanged on a dependency property, but since I didn't implement Inotifypropertychanged, I am wondering how i do that.

I think DependencyObject already implements Inotifypropertychanged, so I have access to this:

```
OnPropertyChanged(new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(property, old value, new value));
```

However, inserting the same object into both the old value and new value slots results in the PropertyChanged event not firing (I assume the implementation checks whether the two values are the same before firing the event).  I want to avoid creating a new object if possible. I guess one option is to override OnPropertyChanged. Nope that also requires me to have a dependency propertychanged event args.

Comment: Note that can raise a property changed with `null` as the property name if you want to say that all property values could have changed.  This is useful when something impacts a large number of properties and you want to send a single notification after having applied all the changes, rather than notifying incrementally along the way as each partial change is made.

Answer (score 1):

Update

```
OnPropertyChanged("TimeScale");
```

to

```
OnPropertyChanged("GraphTimeScale");
```

Or,

you can wrap the `TimeScale` class with an `ObservableObject` so that you can subscribe to object change events and raise them from there.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff653818.aspx

Comment: Didn't have enough data in my question I think. Going to try to revise it

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` notification of `NumberOfUnits`, and then raise `OnPropertyChanged("GraphTimeScale")` in the property changed event handler.

Would be interested if there is a better way though.